# PHP: Complex Multi-Line RegEx, Tilde delimeters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to generate a regex that will match the following format:

```
-1 LKSJDF LSAALSKJ~
Syjsdf
lkjdf
This block may contain multiple characters including digits, colons, etc.  Any character other than a tilde.
 ~
```

I'm currently using this:

```
/(-\d|\d)\s([^$\~][a-zA-Z\s]*)\~\n/s
```

Which matches the first line fine.  I need to capture the -1 through 60 that begins the pattern, the words after the space and up until the first tilde.  I then need to capture all of the text BETWEEN the tildes.

I'm not the strongest with regex in the first place, but I'm having trouble getting this to work without also capturing the tildes.

Comment: Try `'/^(-?\d+)\s+([^~]*)~([^~]+)~/m'`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB5dG3/1). I am not sure what you mean by `through 60`. Do you want to only match integer values between -1 and 60?

Comment: .... it looks like that works perfectly, i'm going to run it through a test, but can you post that as an answer?  So I can approve it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'/^(-?\d+)\s+([^~]*)~([^~]+)~/m'
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB5dG3/1)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `/m` modifier `^` does not match start of string any longer)
- `(-?\d+)` - (Group 1) a one or zero `-` followed with one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace symbols (to only match tab and regular spaces, use `\h+` instead)
- `([^~]*)` - (Group 2) zero or more characters other than a `~` (you can force to match these characters on the first line only by adding a `\n\r` to the negated character class - `[^~\n\r]`)
- `~` - a literal leading tilde
- `([^~]+)` - (Group 3) one or more characters other than a tilde
- `~` - a literal trailing tilde

If you need to only match these strings if the number is an integer between -1 and 60, you can use

```
'/^(-1|[1-5]?[0-9]|60)\s+([^~]*)~([^~]+)~/m'
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB5dG3/2)

Here, the first group matches integer numbers from -1 to 60 with `(-1|[1-5]?[0-9]|60)` alternation group. `-1` and `60` match literal numbers, and `[1-5]?[0-9]` matches one or zero (optional) digit from 1 to 5 (replace with `[0-5]?` if a leading zero is allowed) and then any one digit may follow.

Comment: That works perfectly.  I feel like an idiot, because I was on the right track, just formatting issues and not working through it properly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a tip: never call yourself names, we should think positive of ourselves. And another pair of eyes is always handy when something puzzles you.